# Validation Ignored with PostBackUrl or Response.Redirect Using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, postbackurl

I have a form with some custom validation. There is a button on the form that should take the user to a 'confirm page' to show all the details of an order.

On-Page Validation

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBillingLastName" Name="txtBillingLastName" 
runat="server"  CssClass="txtbxln required"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CustomValidator 
    ID="CustomValidatorBillLN" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtBillingLastName"
    OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorBillLN_ServerValidate"
    ValidateEmptyText="True">
    </asp:CustomValidator>
```

Validator code behind

```
protected void CustomValidatorBillLN_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        args.IsValid = isValid(txtBillingLastName);
    }
```

However, if I add PostBackUrl or Response.Redirect to the button onclick method, all the validation controls are ignored.

I could call all the validation methods with the onclick method, but that seems a less than an elegant solution.

I've tried setting CausesValidation=False with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course that validation IS ignored if you redirect unconditionally. You should call `this.IsValid` before you redirect like

```
protected btRedirect_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
   if ( this.IsValid )
     Response.Redirect( ... );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code

```
void ValidateBtn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  { 
     // Display whether the page passed validation.
     if (Page.IsValid) 
     {
        Message.Text = "Page is valid.";
     }

     else 
     {
        Message.Text = "Page is not valid!";
     }
  }

  void ServerValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
  {
     try 
     {
        // Test whether the value entered into the text box is even.
        int i = int.Parse(args.Value);
        args.IsValid = ((i%2) == 0);
     }

     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        args.IsValid = false;
     }
  }
```

And Html side code

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">

  <h3>CustomValidator ServerValidate Example</h3>

  <asp:Label id="Message"  
       Text="Enter an even number:" 
       Font-Name="Verdana" 
       Font-Size="10pt" 
       runat="server"/>

  <p>

  <asp:TextBox id="Text1" 
       runat="server" />

  &nbsp;&nbsp;

  <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"
       ControlToValidate="Text1"
       ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate"
       OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
       Display="Static"
       ErrorMessage="Not an even number!"
       ForeColor="green"
       Font-Name="verdana" 
       Font-Size="10pt"
       runat="server"/>

  <p>

  <asp:Button id="Button1"
       Text="Validate" 
       OnClick="ValidateBtn_OnClick" 
       runat="server"/>
```

For further information check [Custom validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx)

Hope my answer help you to solve your problem.